# Storyboard file 'MainStoryboard_iPad~ipad.storyboardc' was not found

Tags: iphone, ios7, storyboard, xcode5, ios6.1

I am attempting to validate my iOS project before uploading it to the App Store.  It's an iPhone app that runs fine in the simulator and on my iPhone test device.  It works fine in iOS 6.1 and iOS 7.

When I run the Validate check in Xcode Organizer, I repeatedly get 1 error and 1 warning.

Error is:

> Storyboard file 'MainStoryboard_iPad~ipad.storyboardc' was not found.  Please ensure the specified file is included in the bundle with any required device modifiers appended to the filename.

Warning is:

> Missing recommended icon file.  The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone/iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format.

I have spent days (weeks?) searching for an answer to similar questions that might resolve the error message.  Nothing works ... and I've tried a lot of things that seemed to have worked for others.

Perhaps there really is something wrong in my code / bundle creation ... help!  I can't find it.  Since I get the same 2 messages every time I try and validate the project, no matter what I change, I'm starting to wonder if, somehow, the changes I'm making are not making it through to the bundle that is getting validated each time?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I stopped trying to resolve the error messages I was getting in the Validate step and began following my hunch that the bundle changes I was making were not getting through to the bundle that was being validated.  I read posts about how to create an Archive "ipa" file.  Following those instructions, I was able to create a new and up to date ipa file that did validate and I was able to upload to the App Store for review.

Comment: Even though OP marked this answer, it doesn't address his question besides saying "just ignore the issue". The answer below gives the actual solution.

Answer (score 33):

Goto your Project view, click Targets, goto General tab and look at Deployment Info settings.
In the Devices selection box, you will see iPhone in your case.

Perform the next steps:

1. select iPad
2. Delete the text Storyboard-iPad in the 'Main Interface' Choice box so it is empty
3. Press cmd-s to save (If not saves automatically)
4. select iPhone again in the Devices selection box
5. Build your project again and archive it again 5.

Problem should be solved now.

Answer (score 17):

To fix the **error**, just open the project's info.plist file and remove the value for the key `Main storyboard file base name (iPad)` (or `UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad`).

[image]

Also, you should be able to fix the **warning** by adding an app icon of the size/type specified in the warning message.

Don't forget to re-archive after making these changes.

Answer (score 2):

This happens, when you change the default storyboard name for iPhone App (even you not targeting to iPad).

**In Project > Targets (App)> General > Deployment Info**

1. Just change Device to iPad and then select the default storyboard of iPhone.
2. Change back Device to iPhone

Answer (score 1):

I have exact the same problem. I'm working on a universal app that has 2 storyboard (both iPhone and ipad) and I accidentally deleted the iPad storyboard while I was making the localisation, then I re-added the iPad storyboard(maybe I did it incorrectly), the next time I submit the binary, the Error-itms-90029 occurs(gone through the validation but failed at the submission, strange case aye~).

I solved this problem by once again deleting the the iPad storyboard, and again re-insert it. and now it is fine. careful when you re-insert it, you also need to check it in the "Build Phases >> Copy Bundle Resources", if you see the storyboard icon showing properly then it is fine.

Comment: Fixed that issue by remove and re-add MainStoryboard~ipad.storyboard file.